# Console based English dictionary app

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to programming. I wrote this following console based app in Python. It's an English dictionary app. If the user inputs the desired word that he/she wishes to search for, then this app should be able to display the definition, example(used in a sentence), synonyms, origins, phonetics, parts of speech of the searched word. It's kinda like PyDictionary, which is a package; on the other hand, it's a full-functional(so far...) app and it uses different online resources. This app is depended on BeautifulSoup and requests packages. I hope someone can point me to make it better and shorter and if there's any mistake in the code.

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


def server_one(url):  # Oxford online dictionary
    """ Server_one scrapping algorithm to get essential information regarding the searched word """

    soup = get_soup(url)

    try:
        definition = soup.select_one('.ind').get_text(strip=True)  # Scraps first definition
    except AttributeError:
        definition = 'NOT FOUNT'

    try:
        example = soup.select_one('.exg').get_text(strip=True)  # Scraps first example
    except AttributeError:
        example = 'NOT FOUNT'

    try:
        parts_of_speech = soup.select_one('.pos').get_text(strip=True).capitalize()  # Gets the POS
    except AttributeError:
        parts_of_speech = 'NOT FOUNT'

    try:
        synonyms = soup.select_one('.exs').get_text(strip=True).split(', ')  # Collects all the synonyms
    except AttributeError:
        synonyms = 'NOT FOUNT'

    if 'NOT FOUNT' in synonyms:
        synonyms_tobe_sent = ''
    else:
        synonyms_tobe_sent = [cap.capitalize() for cap in synonyms]  # Capitalizes all the elements in the list

    try:
        origins = []
        for ori in soup.select('.senseInnerWrapper'):  # Scraps all the origins in a list
            if len(ori.text) < 400:
                origins.append(ori.text)
    except AttributeError:
        origins = 'NOT FOUNT'

    try:
        phonetics = soup.select_one('.phoneticspelling').get_text(strip=True)  # Gets the phonetics
    except AttributeError:
        phonetics = 'NOT FOUNT'

    try:
        next_definitions = []
        for tag in soup.select('.ind'):  # Gathers all possible definitions of the searched word
            next_definitions.append(tag.text)
        try:
            next_definitions.pop(0)  # Removes the first definition since it's already used before
        except IndexError:
            pass
    except AttributeError:
        next_definitions = 'NOT FOUNT'

    if example != 'NOT FOUNT':
        example_tobe_sent = example[1:-1].capitalize() + '.'  # Removes colons(') from the string and adds a (.)
    else:
        example_tobe_sent = 'NOT FOUNT'

    return definition, example_tobe_sent, next_definitions, parts_of_speech, synonyms_tobe_sent, origins, phonetics


def search_word():
    """ This function returns the searched word in lower format """

    word = input('Word that you wish to search\n>>> ').lower()
    return word


def url_server_one():
    """ A function to get correct URL for the server_one """

    w = search_word()
    new_w = w.replace(' ', '_')  # If a word has space then it gets _ instead, e.g. 'look up' turns into 'look_up'
    if ' ' in w:
        url = 'https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/%s' % new_w  # URL with underscore(_)
    else:
        url = 'https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/%s' % w  # URL without underscore
    data = (url, w)  # To make two variables as a tuple
    return data


def get_soup(url):
    """ This returns the bs4 soup object that will be used for scrapping """

    source_code = r.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup_data = BS(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    return soup_data


def display_dict():
    """ A function to display all the collected information in a desired format, currently supports only server_one """

    url, title = url_server_one()
    def_, exam, next_defs, part_sp, synos, ori, phonet = server_one(url)

    print('\nDefinition of %s:\n%s\n' % (title.capitalize(), def_))
    print('Parts of Speech:\n%s\n' % part_sp)
    print('Phonetics of %s:\n%s\n' % (title.capitalize(), phonet))
    print('Example of %s as follows:\n%s\n' % (title.capitalize(), exam))

    print('Synonyms:')
    if synos != '' or synos != []:
        print(', '.join(synos))
        print()
    if len(synos) < 1:
        print('NOT FOUND\n')

    print('Origins:')
    if ori != '' or ori != []:
        for i in ori:
            if i != '' or i != 'NOT FOUNT':
                print(i, sep=' ')
            print()
    if len(ori) < 1:
        print('NOT FOUND\n')

    print('Some other definition(s) of %s:' % title.capitalize())
    if next_defs != '' or next_defs != []:
        for i in next_defs:
            if i != '' or i != 'NOT FOUNT':
                print('* ' + i.capitalize() + '\n')
    if len(next_defs) < 1:
        print('NOT FOUND\n')


def try_():
    """ Part of repeat() function that returns integer value """

    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input('Press 1 to search again\n'
                      'Press 2 to quit'))
            if x in {1, 2}:
                return x
            print('Either press 1 or 2')
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter an integer')


def repeat():
    """ A function to repeat the process of searching over again and quit from the app """

    _try = try_()
    if _try == 1:
        display_dict()
    else:
        quit()


def main():
    print('Welcome to PyEngDict V1.0 by AJ\n')
    display_dict()  # Initially launches the app's search option
    while True:
        repeat()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: A screenshot of the app]

Comment: You have multiple `try`s that can be combined into a for loop; also "found" is spelled "found", not "fount" (minor).

Comment: @BarryCarter thanks, man. Instead of saying could u plz illustrate how it's done? I hope i know how to spell found, but that's not an issue here.

Comment: I'm too lazy to actually show you, but consider:`definition = soup.select_one('.ind')`. You do this over and over again with `ind` replaced with different strings. That highly suggests doing something like `definition = soup.select_one(i)`, where `i` is a loop variable.

Comment: @BarryCarter thanks, for not being too lazy while explaining this.. got some ideas..

Answer (score 3):

Here are some of the things I would work on:

- *variable naming* - try to name your variables in a *descriptive* way - variable names like `i` (note that it is not used as an index variable but as a next origin or definition) or `ori`, `part_sp` are not clear enough - it takes time to understand what are they used for. Making variables shorter is not the right motivation when it hurts readability.
- `if ori != '' or ori != []:` could be replaced with `if ori:`, `if next_defs != '' or next_defs != []:` can be replaced with `if next_defs:`
- I am not sure you actually need both `w` and `new_w` inside the `url_server_one()` function - you can replace a space with an undescore for every search string:

  ```
  def url_server_one():
      """A function to get correct URL for the server_one."""

      word = search_word().replace(' ', '_')
      url = 'https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/' + word

      return (url, word)
  ```
- handling `AttributeError` in this part does not make sense - it would not be thrown by `.select()` or `.text` since `.select()` would return an empty list if no matching tags found and a list of `Tag` instances which all would have `text` attribute. In other words, `AttributeError` would not be thrown:

  ```
  try:
      origins = []
      for ori in soup.select('.senseInnerWrapper'):  # Scraps all the origins in a list
          if len(ori.text) < 400:
              origins.append(ori.text)
  except AttributeError:
      origins = 'NOT FOUNT'
  ```

  (same goes for the block where you collect `next_definitions`)
- you can use a list comprehension to define `origins` list:

  ```
  origins = [ori.text for ori in soup.select('.senseInnerWrapper') if len(ori.text) < 400]
  ```
- you can use a [multi-line string](https://www.smallsurething.com/multi-line-strings-in-python/) instead of multiple `print` calls with new-line characters

There are also these `try` and `except AttributeError:` repetitive blocks. There are multiple ways to address that. One is to switch to a dictionary-based approach, first define a mapping between field names and CSS selectors, something like:

```
selectors = {
    'definition': '.ind',
    'example': '.exg',
    'parts_of_speech': '.pos',
    'phoneticspelling': '.phoneticspelling',
    # ...
}

field_values = {}
for field, selector in selectors.items():
    tag = soup.select_one(selector)
    field_values[field] = tag.get_text() if tag is not None else 'NOT FOUND'
```

Comment: thanks, for ur awesome feedback. Learnt some cool tricks from it. If u get a chance could u review first two functions of my revised code and give a feedback?

Comment: @AJ please do not change the original code in the question and, instead, post a separate question as a next round of a code review. Thanks!

Comment: okay, did't know i couldn't do that. Btw, did u have a look at my deleted code? @alecxe

Comment: @AJ well, first of all, the revision is not lost (you can find it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/175883/revisions)). This is just how things work on the Code Review site ([reference](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)). Please post the modified code in a separate thread and I'll have a closer look there. Thanks for understanding!